# How to get status enable or disable for auto start permission in android programatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to check the status of Auto Start permission in Vivo phone, I got solution to open that setting but I am not able to check status is on/off in permission Auto Start for my app. If it is enable then do not want to open that Auto Start setting.

How can I solve this?

Using below code I open Auto start setting.

```
    try {
        val intent = Intent()
        val manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER
        if ("xiaomi".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true)) {
            intent.component = ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")
        } else if ("oppo".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true)) {
            intent.component = ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")
        } else if ("vivo".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true)) {
            intent.component = ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity")
        } else if ("Letv".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true)) {
            intent.component = ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity")
        } else if ("Honor".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true)) {
            intent.component = ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity")
        }
        val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", context.getPackageName(), null)
        intent.data = uri
        val list = context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
        if (list.size > 0) {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("exc", e.toString())
    }
```

Comment: It's not possible to check for autostart using code. These custom ROMs do not expose any API to check for this option. Best is what You already did, re-direct them to settings page. Just educate your user why you are doing this before you transit.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way that you can get to know this. One way you can do this is to talk with the OEM and get your app whitelisted, so that it is auto started by default.